# How would i display multiple location in Mapbox

Tags: android, mapbox

[image: Map]

Hi i am making an app which displays multiple location on a map. So far i have managed to show one location on the map how would i display multiple markers on the map. I am using mapbox with android studio.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(@NonNull MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
    map = mapboxMap;
    mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.OUTDOORS,this);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {

    super.onStart();
    mapView.onStart();
}


@Override
public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {

    SymbolManager sm = new SymbolManager(mapView,map,style);


    SymbolOptions symbolOptions = new SymbolOptions()
            .withLatLng(new LatLng(latitude,longitude))
            .withDraggable(false)
            .withIconImage("suitcase-15")
            .withIconColor("black")
            .withIconSize(2.5f);


    Symbol symbol = sm.create(symbolOptions);

    String latitudeLocation= Double.toString(latitude);
    String longitudeLocation = Double.toString(longitude);


    lat.setText( latitudeLocation);
    lon.setText(longitudeLocation);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep adding more `SymbolOptions` objects to the `SymbolManager`.

See the plugins test app `SymbolActivity`: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/plugins/testapp/activity/annotation/SymbolActivity.java#L119-L125

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop your code to insert multiple location.
Like

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
SymbolManager sm = new SymbolManager(mapView,map,style);


    SymbolOptions symbolOptions = new SymbolOptions()
            .withLatLng(new LatLng(latitude,longitude))
            .withDraggable(false)
            .withIconImage("suitcase-15")
            .withIconColor("black")
            .withIconSize(2.5f);


    Symbol symbol = sm.create(symbolOptions);

    String latitudeLocation= Double.toString(latitude);
    String longitudeLocation = Double.toString(longitude);


    lat.setText( latitudeLocation);
    lon.setText(longitudeLocation);

}
```